# What is the correct preposition for environs?

Tags: prepositions

According to [Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/environs?q=environs), *environs* is "the area surrounding a place". I am writing a text about Barsian - a small city which is located around Isfahan. Can I write Barsian is located in Isfahan environs? Is **in** the correct preposition here?

Comment: Personally, and I know this may not help, I find it a very un-useful word and I avoid it. "Barsian is located in the vicinity of Isfahan" sounds much better to me.

Comment: @Catija "Vicinity" is a great word but to me it suggests "close to" or "nearby" whereas from Wikipedia I believe that Isfahan is a (large) province that contains Barsian. Hence I would prefer to say "Barsian is located in the province of Isfahan" (or "... located within the ..."). Suppose the town Wxyz is in a province adjacent to Isfahan and close to their shared border, then I would happily say "Wxyz  is located in the vicinity of Isfahan". I agree with your comment on "environs".

Answer (score 2):

To me the word "environs" suggests an area close to a town.

My first alternative thought on wording was "*Barsian is located in in the suburbs of (the town or city of) Isfahan*", but then [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barsian_mosque_and_minaret) told me that Isfahan is a province of Iran and that Barsian is a village. So I think correct phrases would include:

> Barsian is located in in the province of Isfahan
>
> Barsian is located in in the Isfahan province
>
> The Isfahan province contains Barsian
>
> The Isfahan province contains the Barsian village
>
> The Isfahan province contains the village of Barsian

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you found this definition of **environ** because your definition describes it as a noun whereas **environ** is a verb that means:

> [surround, enclose](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/environ).

Perhaps you confused it with **environment**.

On the other hand I don't know anything about those cities, Isfahan and Barsian. But if Bastian surrounds or encloses Isfahan you can write:

> Barsian environs (or surrounds or encloses) Isfahan.

Comment: 'Environs' is a perfectly good plural noun - loads of dictionaries include it.

Comment: @ssav, To err is human.